# Are there any non-Zend Google Contacts library for PHP?

Tags: php, google-api, google-contacts-api

I need that because i'm already using the Agavi framework and things will get messy if i tried integrating Zend too. Is there an equivalent of facebook-php sdk for Google Contacts?

Comment: Have you looked at the APIs http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the [protocol](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html) on the Google Contacts API i can tell that it's mostly REST and XML based. I don't know Agavi but if it contains some kind of REST client it shouldn't be too hard to implement it yourself.

As for the real answer to your question ... not that I or [google](http://www.google.be/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=google+contacts+php+-zend#sclient=psy&hl=nl&source=hp&q=google+contacts+api+php+-zend&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=5aee883b1881b85d) know of.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you'd think it would get messy, as Zend Framework components are (by design) very loosely coupled and uniquely namespaced. You can use Zend_Gdata all by itself if you like, and it won't interfere with anything that Agavi is doing.